# Prevent ajax call from firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call

```
$('#button1').on('click', function(e){
    $.ajax({
      url:  url,
      type: 'POST',
      async: true,
      dataType: 'json',
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){

      },
      error: function(){}
    });
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Now here the response is received after 10 minutes . So the ajax call is called multiple times. Why does this happen / how can we ensure that ajax call is called only once?

Comment: "Now here the response is received after 10 minutes" - What? And how are you firing the call? The code provided isn't the source of the problem

Comment: It happens on a button call. Updated the code.

Comment: Do you mean that users hit the button more than once because it takes so long?

Comment: Why is your request taking 10 minutes? If you want to prevent the code from calling the ajax source more than once, you can make a variable called "loading" and check/set it before your ajax call and in the success callback

Comment: If the user is hitting the button more than once because the response takes so long, set the button to disabled on click, then re-enable it in your success/error callbacks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

An alternative to disabling the button would be to use the [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method and re-bind the event handler after callback:

```
var clickHandler = function(e){
    $.ajax({
      url:  url,
      type: 'POST',
      async: true,
      dataType: 'json',
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
        $('#button1').one('click', clickHandler);
      },
      error: function(){}
    });
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
}

$('#button1').one('click', clickHandler);
```

Comment: With symfony 2 it's the only one way who worked for me :) Thank you

Comment: I would like to point out that this solution also works if, by any chance your function is inside a function that executes each time the event is triggered (like  [link](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) keyup for example), but you want your ajax to be called just once.

Comment: Yehh it works for me, and i think @thvs86 also right sometime it is happen function inside function.

Comment: Adding `e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;` at the end helped for me.

Answer (score 15):

I was facing the same issue and it works when I set `async: false`.
Sample code will be like this

```
$('#button1').on('click', function(e){
    $.ajax({
      url:  url,
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){

      },
      error: function(){}
    });
});
```

Comment: Its help me a lot.

Comment: You should not do that, unless you want your UI to get hanged for sometime

Comment: I have added a loading image before calling ajax function but image does not display if i use async: false. Not working for me.

Answer (score 9):

Simply call `.off()` right before you call `.on()`.

This will remove all event handlers:

```
$(element).off().on('click', function() {
    // function body
});
```

To only remove registered 'click' event handlers:

```
$(element).off('click').on('click', function() {
    // function body
});
```

Answer (score 6):

As per the answer by Brennan,

```
$('#button1').on('click', function(e){
    $('#button1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $.ajax({
      url:  url,
      type: 'POST',
      async: true,
      dataType: 'json',
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
         $('#button1').removeAttr('disabled');
      },
      error: function(){}
    });
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Here the button will be disabled and will be enabled on `success`

Answer (score 0):

For me I have the same problem using jsonp

after 2 minutes without answer $ajax seem to retransmit the request...

I suspect is a browser issue because jsonp is switched to <script... tag

and without answer I suspect the browser restransmits the request after ~ 2 minutes...

My workarround was done by responding anything asap and after 10 minutes my script ask for success or not...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and updating async to true did the trick for me. Sample code:

```
var clickHandler = function(e){
    $.ajax({
      url:  url,
      type: 'POST',
      async: true,
      dataType: 'json',
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
        $('#button1').one('click', clickHandler);
      },
      error: function(){}
    });
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
}

$('#button1').one('click', clickHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `one()`, as shown in other actions, or you can also create a deactivation logic for the click handler which can be reactivated whenever you need. In the example below `go` will work exactly once, unless `again` is clicked, in which case `go` is again reactivated for the purpose of a single event handling. This is handy if you want to reuse the same button multiple times to send AJAX, but you want to deactivate its event while waiting for a response. Of course, the `disabled` HTML attribute is also your friend.

```js
$('#button1').on('click', function(e) {
    if (!this.classList.contains("foo")) alert(1);
    this.classList.add("foo");
    this.value = "waiting";
});

$('#button2').on('click', function(e) {
    let btn = $('#button1');
    btn.removeClass("foo").val("go");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="button1" value="go">

<input type="button" id="button2" value="again">
```