# Not fireing twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Goal:
When you press on the button, the value from the textbox shall be displayed one time below the formula

Problem:
When I click on the button, the data will be displayed twice.

I tried this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475445/prevent-ajax-call-from-firing-twice) below below but it doesn't work

```
  $('#myform').one('submit', clickHandler);

  var clickHandler = function (event) {

      event.preventDefault();

  $("#divProcessing").show();

  $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr("action"),
      type: 'POST',
      async: true,
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (resp) {
          // Hide the "busy" gif:
          $("#divProcessing").hide();

          // Do something useful with the data:
          $("<h3>" + resp.FirstName + " " + resp.LastName + "</h3>").appendTo("#divResult");
      }
  });
```

}

Info:
*Using ASP.net mvc and JQuery
*The foundation of this code is from this [page](http://johnatten.com/2013/12/22/asp-net-mvc-show-busy-indicator-on-form-submit-using-jquery-and-ajax/)

```
namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LongRunningDemoProcess(DemoViewModel model)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return Json(model, "json");
        }


    }


    public class DemoViewModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

}





<h3>Enter Your Name and Submit:</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm("LongRunningDemoProcess", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myform", name = "myform" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)

    <input type="submit" name="operation" id="process" value="process" />
}

// We want to show this while the server process is running:
<div id="divProcessing">
    <p>Processing, please wait . . . <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pictofoundry-pro-vector-set/512/Alien-16.png"></p>
</div>

// We want to display the result from our submission in here:
<div id="divResult">

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

      // Hide the "busy" Gif at load:
      $("#divProcessing").hide();

      // Attach click handler to the submit button:
      $('#process').click(function () {
          $('#myform').submit();
      });

      // Handle the form submit event, and make the Ajax request:
      $("#myform").on("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Show the "busy" Gif:
        $("#divProcessing").show();
        var url = $(this).attr("action");
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: "POST",
          data: formData,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (resp) {

            // Hide the "busy" gif:
            $("#divProcessing").hide();

            // Do something useful with the data:
            $("<h3>" + resp.FirstName + " " + resp.LastName + "</h3>").appendTo("#divResult");
          }
        })
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need a separate "click" handler on the "submit" button. I would suspect this is why it's firing twice:

```
$('#process').click(function () {
      $('#myform').submit();
  });
```

You are explicitly telling the form to be submitted, but pressing any button with `type="submit"` within a form will trigger the submit event automatically, without extra code. Therefore you're effectively ordering an extra submission of the form. Remove the click handler and it should just submit once.

Comment: I removed the code "$('#process').click(function () {
      $('#myform').submit();
  });" and everything works

Comment: Thank you for your help!