# jquery function is being called more than once on single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am having more than one button with same class name and different id. but when I click on button, it's called for more than one everytime. for information about code in action, please see the video : https://nimb.ws/3RMoNP

Here is my code

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete_attachment_confirmation", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var attachment_id = $(this).data('attachmentid');
    $('#delete_attachment_confirmation_'+attachment_id).attr("disabled", true);
    $('#delete_attachment_confirmation_'+attachment_id).text("Deleting file");


    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url('attachment/delete_attachment/')?>"+$(this).data('attachmentid'),
      type: "GET",  
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data){

        $("#row_"+attachment_id).remove();

        $("#attachment_message_body").text(data);

        $('#delete_attachment_'+attachment_id).modal('hide');

        // attachment message
        $('#attachment_message').modal('show');

        // modal issue removal trick
        $('.modal-backdrop').removeClass('modal-backdrop');

      }
    }); 
});


<button class="btn btn-danger delete_attachment_confirmation" id="delete_attachment_confirmation_<?=$row->id?>" data-attachmentid="<?=$row->id?>" ><?php echo $this->lang->line('btn_modal_delete');?>
```

updated button code

```
<button class="btn btn-danger delete_attachment_confirmation" id="delete_attachment_confirmation_<?=$row->id?>" data-attachmentid="<?=$row->id?>" ><?php echo $this->lang->line('btn_modal_delete');?>
```

Highlighted part is showing us that ajax function is being called more than once.

[image]

Comment: There is a topic here may help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475445/prevent-ajax-call-from-firing-twice

Comment: I suggest that you properly trace the issue by commenting out the ajax part and then try printing a message to console to confirm if it's the click event firing multiple times or something is wrong with your ajax code which is firing it multiple times.

Comment: A simple test did not yield the result you reported event with having two buttons with the same class: https://jsbin.com/niyidiyuho/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Sorted out. Thanks for your input. I have used solution mentioned in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775455/ajax-prevent-multiple-request-on-click

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in above JS code that is causing it run twice, just that button does not have closing tag and multiple buttons without closing tags and having same class may be the reason, i just ran your code in codepan and it is running fine.

```
<button class="btn btn-danger delete_attachment_confirmation" id="delete_attachment_confirmation_<?=$row->id?>" data-attachmentid="<?=$row->id?>" ><?php echo $this->lang->line('btn_modal_delete');?></button>
```

https://codepen.io/balramsinghindia/pen/OJLzjbo

Comment: checked code .. button code is having closing tag. I have updated in question.

Comment: on click is being called one time only ( checked by alert) but when i tried with ajax, it's being called (ajax function ) more than 1 time.

Comment: I am totally clueless as same type of functionality i am using everywhere in function and running fine in all cases except this

Comment: No worry mate, we will solve it, may i ask you few more questions to understand the problem in detail?

Comment: It it calling twice if you put alert inside success of AJAX call?

Comment: How did you get to know that it is called more than once, can you please add more alerts where you suspect that this code is called twice?

It is hard to understand from video without having context of expected vs wrong behaviour.

Comment: In video check the developer window.. once you click on button, with same id, ajax function is being called more than 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199045/discussion-between-dhavalthakor-and-balram-singh).

Answer (score -1):

I have used solution provided in this question.

[Ajax, prevent multiple request on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775455/ajax-prevent-multiple-request-on-click)

Comment: Hi, the code in the question look fine for me. I suggest you look carefully to understand the problem rather than apply a workaround. I think the above code is included twice in the html

Comment: Please avoid copying someone else code and posting that as answer without modifying that first because it has no meaning here now. The code is only relevant to the question where you copied it from.

Comment: I have put the code just for reference and also provided the link of original answer.

Comment: @BangDao I will look into that.

Comment: @BangDao I did check there wasn't code twice in document.

Answer (score -2):

```
  $(".classNamw").unbind().click(function() {
//Your stuff
  })
```

Comment: this function come to client browser in ajax while loading html content on some button click

Comment: Not working. and when I have commented ajax request and tried with alert() popup, Popup is showing only 1 time and while ajax request is being made more than 1 time