# Ajax Making Mutiple Requests to the API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have just started learning javascript and what I am doing is making request to my Django API. So I found I can use Ajax requests to do so.

SO I made a search bar that would call the API after waiting 1 sec on the `keyup` action.

```
input.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timout = setTimeout(function () {
    runScript(input.value);
  }, 1000);
});
```

The runscript function is the one making Ajax requests

```
function runScript(input) {
  var jqXHR = $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8090/api/movie/?name=" + input,
    datatype: 'json',
    success: callbackFunc
  });
  return jqXHR.responseText;
}
```

and the callbackFunc is what I would like to do with the response

```
function callbackFunc(response) {
   // do something
}
```

The problem is that ajax is making multiple requests to the API. How do I stop Ajax from making multiple requests ?

Related: [Prevent ajax call from firing twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475445/prevent-ajax-call-from-firing-twice/26475770), [Ajax, prevent multiple request on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775455/ajax-prevent-multiple-request-on-click)

Comment: The `setTimeout` should prevent it from calling the API more than once a second. If you want it to be less frequent, change `1000` to a large number.

Comment: The `runscript` function is being called only once (as I want) but the `callbackFunc` is being called multiple times. Suppose I type `Avengers` in the input field, then the runscript function is being called once, but looking at my API console, it has multiple requests like this `"GET /api/movie/?name=Avengers HTTP/1.1" 200`

Comment: That can't happen. The callback function is only called once per AJAX request. And only one AJAX request is made per call to `runscript`.

Comment: It's not relevant to the problem, but why does `runScript` return `jqXHR.responseText`? The response hasn't been received yet.

Comment: @kunal it will be not possible, check. callbackFunc will be called same as runscript.

Comment: Set an XHR breakpoint in the debugger to see where the other requests are coming from, they might not be from this code.

Comment: Please verify there me be OPTION call, not. the GET call. use console log.. to validate

Comment: I am sorry, using `Console.log` i found that the `runscript` is being called multiple times. As you said @Barmar in your first comment, if I change 1000 to a large number, it would slow the results, is there any other way around ?

Comment: Don't you want it called frequently? You put it in `keyup`, so it's supposed to update as the user types, not wait for them to finish.

Comment: If you want to wait for them to finish, run the function in the `change` event or the form's `submit` event.

Comment: use onchange event, it will trigger when change only. or use key-down,

Comment: You have a typo. `timeout` vs `timout` which did you declare ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **stopImmediatePropagation** method which is meant for cases like this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation.

> If several listeners are attached to the same element for the same event type, they are called in the order in which they were added. If stopImmediatePropagation() is invoked during one such call, no remaining listeners will be called.

You only need to add the method call on you timeout function like this

```
timeout = setTimeout(function () {
e.stopImmediatePropagation()
  runScript(input.value);
}, 1000);
```

Full fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/zgranda/fujw6tvp/9/